# Hosting a multi-threaded mvc app in AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, hosting, appharbor

I'm building a simple Restful service to aggregate data from 3 external services.  I'm planning on calling each external service on its own thread.  Do I need I different 3 workers for this in [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)?  What if I decide to collect the data in the background every x amount of time and store it on my server. Do I need a background worker to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spin up multiple threads from within a single worker, so you'd only need one. Background workers on AppHarbor can be used to do intermittent tasks, the simplest way to accomplish this is to just sleep the thread between runs.